# How can i transform divs into buttons?

Tags: html, css

I need to make all this divs into buttons, here is my full code:

```html
    <div class="mc-button full">
      <div type="button" class="title">1.19.3</div>
    </div>
```

I tried add this

```html
    <div class="mc-button full">
      <div type="button" href="about1-19-3.html" class="title">1.19.3</div>
    </div>`
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: `<button>` or `<a>`, possibly with `display: block` as CSS if you want to make them act like a div.

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for are basic introductory tutorials on HTML.  A `div` doesn't *have* a `type` or an `href`.  Do you mean that you want to *add a link* to your HTML?  Any introductory tutorial should cover how to do that.

Comment: Yes i understand but can you explain me? I want to add a link to that `div` button

Comment: You mix a lot of different things here. A **button** is a trigger to fire a script. A **link** connects another resource to your document. An **anchor** directs to another resource. A **div** is just an unspecific block-level container. If you want to use `href` to re-direct do another element you either want to use an anchor or you need JS to add an eventListener to redirect.

Comment: Add an a hyperlink element `<a>` into your div

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
<div class="mc-button full">
  <div type="button" href="about1-19-3.html" class="title">1.19.3</div>
</div>`
```

This should be converted into something like this...

```
<div class="mc-button full">
  <button type="submit" @onclick="location.href("/about1-19-3.html")" class="title">1.19.3</div>
</div>`
```

Or something like this...

```
<div class="mc-button full">
  <a href="/about1-19-3.html" class="title">1.19.3</a>
</div>`
```

Comment: that is not a task for `button type="submit"` (for which you should use an `input type="button"`. Submit is for submitting a form not to open another webpage

Comment: The task which you are expecting for will not be done due to it is not covered with <form> tag. 

And the question is just to make the <div> look like button.

Comment: which is a CSS Task but not by incorrectly using `button type submit` just remove the type attribute and the @ from the onclick attribute

Answer (score 1):

You mix a lot of different things here.

A **button** is a trigger to fire a script.

```html
<button>Text of a button</button>
```

You use this in combination with either `onclick` attribute or directly in JS with an `addEventListener` to fire a script.

A **link** connects another resource to your document.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="" href="">
</head>
```

That connects another resource such as CSS, Favicons to your document.

An **anchor** directs to another resource.

```html
<a href="">Anchor Text</a>
```

that if clickd, will redirect you to another resource by either changing the current tab, opening a new tab or by downloading another resource.

A **div** is just an unspecific block-level container. If you want to use `href` to re-direct do another element you either want to use an anchor or you need JS to add an eventListener to redirect. Markup valid-wise you should use JS:

```html
<div class="mc-button full">
  <div onclick="location.href = 'about1-19-3.html';" class="title">1.19.3</div>
</div>
```

However, with only `1.19.3` as content it mostlikely should be an **anchor**:

```html
<div class="mc-button full">
  <a href="about1-19-3.html" class="title">1.19.3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

why for any reason would you turn a div into a button?
suprise, you also can't add a type attribute to a div.
But if you insist, Here is your answer:

```
<div class="button">Click Me!</div>

 .button {
    width: 130px;
    background-color: rgb(44, 43, 43);
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif, serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button:active {
    background-color: #7c7878;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: just go with @Turgunov Sardor's answer, don't make a div into a button.